# Occasional "Access denied" to 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\' files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

In my ASP.NET MVC application I sometimes get these errors when I try to open or generate LocalReport from Microsoft Reporting Services assembly:

> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException:
>   An error occurred during local report
>   processing. --->
>   Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException:
>   The definition of the report
>   'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\orders\Reports\Reports\Pending
>   Renewals.rdlc' is invalid. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
>   An unexpected error occurred in Report
>   Processing. --->
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access to the path
>   'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\expression_host_b5ec9f67a3ab42cfb53a75588aed6f75.dll' is denied.

or

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException:
>   Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown. --->
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException:
>   An error occurred during local report
>   processing. --->
>   Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException:
>   The definition of the report 'Main
>   Report' is invalid. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
>   An unexpected error occurred in Report
>   Processing. --->
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access to the path
>   'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\expression_host_a1670a6e6b96411790645cb12e50897d.dll' is denied.

What can be the reason? Most of the time it works so it's not security issue. How do I fix it?

Here's [what I've found](http://forums.asp.net/t/1479201.aspx) but I'd not like to use "use fields instead of report parameters" solution.

Comment: I had this issue before, and could not fix it completely. Could not find any details on it either, which sucked...

Comment: Hm, at least now I know few cases (yours and few on internet) where people could not resolve this. If I don't find the answer I'll have to stick with "fake fields as parameters" solution, I suppose.

Comment: anyone find anything on this one? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also faced the same problem. But, when i start my visual studio by "Run As Administrator" Option, the problem wasn't arise anymore.

[image]

Hope, this can help you

Comment: The error happened in IIS, where webapp was not safe to run under admin. But, well, this is at least a workaround.

Comment: For IIS, I think you change your application identity pool property to LocalSystem.