# Report Manager - Access to the temp directory is denied

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to access the Reporting Services 2005 Report Manager locally on a Windows Server 2003 server and I'm getting the following error:

> Access to the temp directory is denied.  Identity 'DOMAIN\login'
>   under which XmlSerializer is running does not have sufficient
>   permission to access the temp directory.  CodeDom will use the user
>   account the process is using to do the compilation, so if the user
>   doesnt have access to system temp directory, you will not be able to
>   compile.  Use Path.GetTempPath() API to find out the temp directory
>   location.

The DOMAIN\login given in the error message is my user login account.  The `Reports` virtual directory in the Default Web Site is configured to use the DefaultAppPool which is configured to run as the `Network Service` identity. The SQL Server Reporting Services windows service is configured to use a separate domain service account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Occasional "Access denied" to 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\' files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131529/occasional-access-denied-to-c-windows-temp-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grant the `NETWORK SERVICE` account read/write/modify access to the `C:\WINDOWS\Temp` directory.

Comment: It did not work for me. I was trying the same thing to set service account for SSRS2008. The built in account = Network service. How do I fix it ? Error message - System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.SS2008\Reporting Services' is denied............etc