# Random error in RDLC - Access to the path C:\Windows\TEMP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I am trying to generate a rdlc report and save it as pdf. It works perfectly fine on the localhost but after deploying it on the server after successfully generation of some files it stops randomly with below exception

**System.UnauthorizedAccessException**

**Access to the path 'C:\Windows\TEMP\expression_host_791eafe958ba48999639e489485a25c1.dll' is denied.**

I have tried giving full access to IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, IIS APPPOOL\MyPOOL, NetworkService and even disposing my localreport and setting permissions, example code below:

```
  using (var lr = new LocalReport())
  {
    PermissionSet permissions = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
    permissions.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
    permissions.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));

    lr.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(permissions);
```

I even restarted the server, recycled app pool and also tried resetting IIS by aspnet_regiis -i

Nothing worked till now. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to delete that file as long as it in TEMP?

Comment: yes I deleted it many times it always stops at a new file, example Access to the path 'C:\Windows\TEMP\expression_host_**c6c51abe9d174433997f1d9bc803a3f5**.dll'

Comment: i can only advice to find out what process is acually using and locking your dll. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565218/how-to-know-what-process-is-using-a-given-file)

Comment: Have you checked that [anti-virus software isn't getting in the way](http://alsaydi.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/report-rendering-fails-in-local-mode.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Occasional "Access denied" to 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\' files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131529/occasional-access-denied-to-c-windows-temp-files)

Answer (score 1):

This mostly an IIS issue.
Change the AppPool's Identity to LocalSystem, you shouldn't get the errors

Comment: I did have the exact same problem as the question and this have fixed the issue but I not convinced about it, I'm migrating to a new server (same OS) and on the old server it is working fine, I'll do further investigation but for the time being thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same scenario you described "It works perfectly fine on the localhost but after deploying it on the server...". What worked for me was:
1- check the new directory where the .rdlc file is located on the server. Get the full path
2- make sure the file and directory are the same in your code (and you're not pointing to the same old location, localhost)